# memoization of recursive function

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I am solving this problem and I solved it recursively. For the larger test case, it was giving me error of time out so I tried to create memoization.

https://leetcode.com/problems/frequency-of-the-most-frequent-element/description/

> The frequency of an element is the number of times it occurs in an
> array.
>
> You are given an integer array of nums and an integer k. In one
> operation, you can choose an index of nums and increment the element
> at that index by 1.
>
> Return the maximum possible frequency of an element after performing
> at most k operations.
>
> Example 1:
>
> Input: nums = [1,2,4], k = 5 Output: 3 Explanation: Increment the
> first element three times and the second element two times to make
> nums = [4,4,4]. 4 has a frequency of 3.

But the problem is that parameter of the function is an array like [1, 2, 4, 6] and k which is an integer value.

I want memoization where I can check for a key which basically checks if the array and k value are already solved or not.

My problem here in the code is that

suppose for a function there is an array [1, 4, 5] and k =3, I check for a key of "1-4-5-3"
and if it is not present I do a recursion call whereas if there was the solution for [1, 5, 4] and k=3, or [5, 1, 4] for k = 3 it should have also said that it is already solved.

```
var maxFrequency = function(nums, k, memo = {}) {
    if(k==0){
        return countFrequency(nums);
    }
    let key = ""
    nums.forEach((element, index)=>{
        key = key + "-" + element
    })
    key = key + "-" +  k
    if(nums[key]){
        return nums[key]
    }
    let result = []
    for(let i=0, _length = nums.length; i<_length; i++){
        let tempArray = [...nums]
        tempArray[i] += 1
        result[i] = maxFrequency(tempArray, k-1)
    }

    nums[key] = Math.max(...result)
    return nums[key]
};

function countFrequency(arr){
    let map = {}
    let maxFreq = 1
    for(let i=0, _length = arr.length; i<_length; i++){
        if(map.hasOwnProperty(arr[i])){
            map[arr[i]] += 1
            if(map[arr[i]]>maxFreq){
                maxFreq = map[arr[i]]
            }
        }
        else{
            map[arr[i]] = 1
        }
    }
    return maxFreq
}
```

It works for smaller data like

> nums = [1,4,8,13] k = 5 got Output 2 for Expected 2

How can I apply memoization to this kind of problem?

Thank you

Comment: `memorization` or `memoiziation` ? that's not the same thing...

Comment: sorry memorization

Comment: otherwise this is not how this problem is solved, you must start by calculating the differences on the highest value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memoization is not going to help reduce the time complexity of your solution. Your algorithm is as brute force as can be, where every possible combination of increment-steps is attempted. With memoization you would eliminate cases where you come to the same result by applying the same increments but in a different order, but:

1. Those "duplicate" cases could be easily avoided by only producing increments from left-to-right and never to an element the *precedes* an element that was already incremented. This approach makes the memoization unnecessary.
2. That still represents a very inefficient algorithm

The right way to approach this problem is:

- Sort the elements in non-decreasing order
- Apply a sliding window algorithm starting with a small window at the left side of the array (a window with 1 element):

  - Extend the window at the right when the window can be flattened to one value with k increments
  - Reduce the window at the left when the window cannot be flattened to one value with k increments

    Note that knowing how many increments are necessary to flatten a window can be deduced with a mathematical (incremental) formula -- you don't really have to perform those increments.
  - Keep track of what the largest window was that could be flattened to one value.
  - Repeat until the window reaches the right end of the array
- Return the number of values in the largest valid window that was found.

Comment: not just with this question but for general cases when there involves an array as a parameter of a function, what are the ways I can use memorization? I found two pointers challenging so wanted to learn and practice recursion and memorization first :D I will try this by two pointer technique

Comment: There is no general "menu" on how to use memoization for any array problem. It depends on the problem. It isn't always the right approach.